# error: no such table UNABLE TO CREATE DB

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying to run a database and make entries into it using the following code to run the database. even though i make proper entries, i still get an error "no such table: user"

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from spello import app
from datetime import datetime

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///spello.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///spello.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key = True)  #defines the id
    email = db.Column(db.String(90))  #defines the Developer's email ID
    URL = db.Column(db.String(120)) #defines the URL

    # created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, email, URL):
        self.email = email
        self.URL = URL

    # self.creation = datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %r>" % self.email
```

i open python in the command line and type the following codes

```
>>> from spello import models
>>> from spello.models import db,User
>>> db.create_all()
>>> u = User('a@b.com','www.asd.com')
>>> db.session.add(u)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

but i when i run sqlite3 in the commandline to check if the database is created, i get the following error

```
(spello)$ sqlite3
sqlite> select * from user;
Error: no such table: user
```

can please sm1 tell where i m going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

What a recent version of the `sqlite3` tool actually says is:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

To open your database, you must actually open it:

```
$ sqlite3 /wherever/you/have/put/spello.db
```